# rectangle vibrating when touching the ground

Tags: python, pygame

everyone. I am trying to learn collisions in tilemaps. I am however having problems with the y-collision. when the player rectangle touches the ground, it starts to vibrate. I have been trying to figure out what the problem is, but to no avail. can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 40, 40)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.vel = 4
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0

        self.is_jump = False
        self.is_stand = False
        self.jump_count = 10

    def handle_input(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.dx = self.vel
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.dx = -self.vel
        else:
            self.dx = 0

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            self.is_jump = True
            self.is_stand = False
            self.dy = -self.jump_count

    def update(self):
        self.handle_input()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), self.rect)
        self.rect.update(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, 40, 40)


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = [
            ["T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "P", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "T"],
            ["T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T"]
        ]

        self.tiles = []
        for row_num, row in enumerate(self.map):
            for col_num, column in enumerate(row):
                if column == "T":
                    rect = pygame.Rect(40*col_num, 40*row_num, 40, 40)
                    self.tiles.append(rect)
                elif column == "P":
                    self.player = Player(40*col_num, 40*row_num)

        self.gravity = 5
        self.grav_rate = 0.3

    def physics(self, obj):
        obj.dy += self.grav_rate
        if obj.dy > self.gravity:
            obj.dy = self.gravity

        for tile in self.tiles:
            coll_x = obj.rect.x + obj.dx, obj.rect.y, obj.rect.w, obj.rect.h - 1
            coll_y = obj.rect.x, obj.rect.y + obj.dy, obj.rect.w, obj.rect.h

            if tile.colliderect(coll_x):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (tile.x, tile.y, 10, 10))
                if obj.dx < 0:
                    obj.rect.left = tile.right
                elif obj.dx > 0:
                    obj.rect.right = tile.left
                obj.dx = 0

            if tile.colliderect(coll_y):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (tile.x, tile.y, 10, 10), 2)
                if obj.dy < 0:
                    obj.dy = -obj.dy
                elif obj.dy > 0:
                    obj.dy = 0
                    obj.is_jump = False
                    obj.is_stand = True
                    obj.rect.bottom = tile.top

            # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), coll_x, 1)
            # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), coll_y, 1)

        obj.rect.x += obj.dx
        obj.rect.y += obj.dy

    def update(self):
        while True:
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    exit()

            for tile in self.tiles:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), tile)

            self.physics(self.player)
            self.player.update()

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)


g = Game()
g.update()
```

Comment: *"looking forward to a reply soon."* - [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update the player's position before doing collision detection and game physics:

```py
class Game:
    # [...]

    def physics(self, obj):
        obj.dy += self.grav_rate
        if obj.dy > self.gravity:
            obj.dy = self.gravity

        obj.rect.x += obj.dx                #<-- INSERT
        obj.rect.y += obj.dy

        for tile in self.tiles:
            coll_x = obj.rect.x + obj.dx, obj.rect.y, obj.rect.w, obj.rect.h - 1
            coll_y = obj.rect.x, obj.rect.y + obj.dy, obj.rect.w, obj.rect.h

            if tile.colliderect(coll_x):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (tile.x, tile.y, 10, 10))
                if obj.dx < 0:
                    obj.rect.left = tile.right
                elif obj.dx > 0:
                    obj.rect.right = tile.left
                obj.dx = 0

            if tile.colliderect(coll_y):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (tile.x, tile.y, 10, 10), 2)
                if obj.dy < 0:
                    obj.dy = -obj.dy
                elif obj.dy > 0:
                    obj.dy = 0
                    obj.is_jump = False
                    obj.is_stand = True
                    obj.rect.bottom = tile.top

        # obj.rect.x += obj.dx               <-- DELETE
        # obj.rect.y += obj.dy
```